# list file name through script in debug mode

Tags: shell, scripting

I have four file

```
ls *a*
aA  Aa  aB  Ba
```

now I have written a simple script `tesh.sh` of listing these files

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -xvf
ls -lrt *a*
```

when I am running this script test.sh, getting this error :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -xvf
ls -lrt *a*

+ ls -lrt '*a*'
ls: cannot access *a*: No such file or directory
```

what I have found it, this error I am getting is because of `-xvf` in `#!/usr/bin/ksh`, but I can't remove this `-xvf` as this is the format to be used and I have to log everything in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-f` turns off file name generation.  Without file name generation, you cannot use globs like `*a*`.  If you need file name generation, turn it back on with `set +f` as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -xvf
set +f
ls -lrt *a*
```

Of course, if you are supposed to use `-f`, there may be a reason for it that you haven't told us.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I too don't know why `-f` is used as I have edited an old script in my organization and the `-xvf` is used in almost all scripts.

Comment: @avinashse That is odd.  The options `-v` or `-f` can be very useful when debugging but it is strange to use them on a working script.  Because shell scripts commonly need file name generation, it is unusual for shell scripts to use `-f`.  Unless your system has some special requirements you haven't told me about,  I think  you should use `set +f` wherever you need it.